# form does not submit, nothing happens when submit button is clicked

Tags: jquery, django

My form just does not want to submit.

My form looks like this:

```
<form id="courseform" name="courseform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="{% url 'checkout' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="useremail" value="{{useremail}}">

<button id="fs-submit-button" class="fs-submit" type="submit">Continue to payment</button>
</form>
```

At the very end of the page I have my javascript:

```
$(".fs-submit").click(function(e) {
    $('#courseform').submit();
});
```

In my base project urls.py:

```
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [

    path('checkout/', user_views.checkout, name='checkout'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Absolutely nothing happens when the button is clicked. No javascript error in the console, nothing.

Comment: `<button id-"fs-submit-button"="" class="fs-submit" type="submit">` should be `<button id="fs-submit-button" class="fs-submit" type="submit">`. I don't know if there is anything else wrong.

Comment: That was copied incorrectly for some reason, fixed it.  I even tried putting in an <a href> tag, and it doesn't redirect to the new url either.

Comment: One important thing to also be careful with while using jQuery is binding all you're code related to DOMs inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: It might be an important factor that this form is going on a template that opens after another form is submitted.  I'm wondering if django somehow blocks the 2nd form from being submitted.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.

Comment: Digging some more, I've come across formsets in Django, used when you have multiple form instances on the same page.  It's worth a shot because both forms are called from the same url view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this correctly in the following two ways. Both are almost the same. You won't need that JQuery function anymore unless you're using it for some error handling/validation etc.

1. Use a `button` outside your form element.

```
<form id="courseform" name="courseform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="{% url 'checkout' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="useremail" value="{{useremail}}">
</form>
<button id="fs-submit-button" value="Submit" form="courseform" class="fs-submit" type="submit">Continue to payment</button>
```

2. Use an `<input>` tag with `type="submit"`.

```
<form id="courseform" name="courseform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="{% url 'checkout' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="useremail" value="{{useremail}}">

<input type="submit" value="Continue to Payment"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem to the "Review and Submit" page of the js script that I'm using which I found here : https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/30/fullscreen-form-interface/

Problem is, I can't find that part of the code anywhere!

Comment: Goddammit, this finally did help in the end. It finally submitted after 2 goddamn weeks. I have no idea why it requires javascript to submit the form when it's an input tag with type = submit, but at least it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to confirm about it. Do you load this form using ajax?
If yes, you can try to use

```
$(document).on("click", ".fs-submit", function(e) {
    $('#courseform').submit();
});
```

because

```
object.click(function(e){});
```

can't be used for form that has been loaded by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, but looks like there is no easy answer to this question.  I did however find in one of the JS files the following:

```
$("form").on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

However after commenting it out, the form is STILL not submitting.  There are no other such functions or event listeners in the javascript, so the issue is most likely caused by something in core Django.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some event stop your submit event.
You can check whats listen your form submit event.

```
var item = $('form');
for(var i=0; i < items.length;i++)
{
    var elem = items[i];
    var data = jQuery.hasData( elem ) && jQuery._data( elem );
    console.log(data.events);
}
```

End check to consol what's listen your submit events.

Answer (score 0):

For Aspx web forms

If using ajax update panels and your button click is in $(document).ready the button click will stop triggering after a partial postback.
You can move the code to Sys.Application.add_load() for the code to work after partial postbacks.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Sys.Application.add_load(){

     };      
    });
```

Or you can check which event listner is got attached against the click
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/get-and-debug-event-listeners